# Change boxplot style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, boxplot

I'm following this [PGFPLOTS manual](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). At first I was enthusiastic with it. However I'm finding some difficulties on doing even basic things. Now I'm trying to change boxplot style.
Up to now I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymode=log,
boxplot/draw direction=y,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
xticklabels={3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
xlabel=number,
ylabel={time[s]},
boxplot/variable width,
boxplot/whisker range={1.57},
]
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
0.090000 \\ 0.440000 \\ 0.120000 \\ 0.060000 \\ 0.320000 \\ 0.230000 \\ 0.440000 \\ 0.020000 \\ 0.150000 \\ 0.180000 \\ 0.000000 \\ 0.290000 \\ 0.000000 \\ 0.110000 \\ 0.260000 \\ 0.110000 \\ 0.000000 \\ 0.450000 \\ 0.040000 \\ 0.140000 \\ 0.030000 \\ 0.120000 \\ 0.140000 \\ 0.310000 \\ 0.060000 \\ 0.060000 \\ 0.110000 \\ 0.120000 \\ 0.120000 \\ 0.120000 \\ 0.130000 \\ 0.010000 \\ 0.400000 \\ 0.010000 \\ 0.030000 \\ 0.170000 \\ 0.000000 \\ 0.100000 \\ 0.150000 \\ 0.160000 \\ 0.060000 \\ 0.100000 \\ 0.010000 \\ 0.600000 \\ 0.260000 \\ 0.110000 \\ 0.150000 \\ 0.220000 \\ 0.140000 \\ 0.010000 \\ 
};
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
0.070000 \\ 0.490000 \\ 0.340000 \\ 0.200000 \\ 0.020000 \\ 1.080000 \\ 6.830000 \\ 0.310000 \\ 0.540000 \\ 0.020000 \\ 0.290000 \\ 0.180000 \\ 0.600000 \\ 0.090000 \\ 0.610000 \\ 1.370000 \\ 0.260000 \\ 0.030000 \\ 2.300000 \\ 0.090000 \\ 3.150000 \\ 0.130000 \\ 0.290000 \\ 0.270000 \\ 1.300000 \\ 0.730000 \\ 0.630000 \\ 0.240000 \\ 10.030000 \\ 0.000000 \\ 0.260000 \\ 0.180000 \\ 3.290000 \\ 2.430000 \\ 1.940000 \\ 0.220000 \\ 0.230000 \\ 0.600000 \\ 1.690000 \\ 0.350000 \\ 3.960000 \\ 0.560000 \\ 9.900000 \\ 0.100000 \\ 0.430000 \\ 0.220000 \\ 0.260000 \\ 0.310000 \\ 0.290000 \\ 0.790000 \\ 
};
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
12.700000 \\ 1.340000 \\ 0.680000 \\ 0.510000 \\ 1.770000 \\ 0.040000 \\ 3.790000 \\ 287.050000 \\ 1.350000 \\ 5.410000 \\ 15.560000 \\ 3.130000 \\ 0.910000 \\ 7.480000 \\ 2.400000 \\ 1.040000 \\ 3.530000 \\ 0.580000 \\ 31.710000 \\ 7.890000 \\ 4.900000 \\ 2.610000 \\ 0.890000 \\ 0.030000 \\ 3.780000 \\ 8.110000 \\ 4.820000 \\ 1.020000 \\ 5.570000 \\ 8.850000 \\ 0.150000 \\ 17.590000 \\ 0.210000 \\ 8.100000 \\ 2.150000 \\ 3.430000 \\ 6.440000 \\ 1.650000 \\ 6.830000 \\ 23.540000 \\ 0.520000 \\ 1.470000 \\ 0.750000 \\ 3.540000 \\ 3.590000 \\ 5.560000 \\ 0.330000 \\ 8.580000 \\ 1.900000 \\ 0.780000 \\ 
};
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
55.720000 \\ 14.910000 \\ 14.950000 \\ 6.010000 \\ 6.530000 \\ 88.300000 \\ 281.500000 \\ 40.150000 \\ 13.410000 \\ 0.910000 \\ 1.650000 \\ 44.320000 \\ 13.410000 \\ 7.330000 \\ 3.510000 \\ 3.440000 \\ 70.400000 \\ 0.750000 \\ 58.200000 \\ 54.880000 \\ 26.450000 \\ 33.760000 \\ 0.700000 \\ 0.050000 \\ 0.290000 \\ 57.120000 \\ 14.300000 \\ 31.110000 \\ 18.560000 \\ 0.480000 \\ 21.330000 \\ 1.150000 \\ 2.220000 \\ 3.880000 \\ 1.780000 \\ 151.250000 \\ 7.770000 \\ 137.920000 \\ 0.500000 \\ 3.010000 \\ 1.990000 \\ 23.180000 \\ 119.590000 \\ 17.500000 \\ 15.870000 \\ 13.630000 \\ 21.850000 \\ 23.530000 \\ 68.720000 \\ 2.900000 \\ 
};
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.190000 \\ 1.940000 \\ 13.400000 \\ 7.400000 \\ 267.300000 \\ 5.940000 \\ 11.050000 \\ 6.510000 \\ 2.940000 \\ 5.450000 \\ 5.240000 \\ 231.000000 \\ 4.480000 \\ 0.680000 \\ 311.290000 \\ 77.470000 \\ 621.200000 \\ 139.080000 \\ 1933.590000 \\ 2.520000 \\ 100.960000 \\ 11.020000 \\ 153.430000 \\ 26.670000 \\ 83.840000 \\ 4.310000 \\ 106.340000 \\ 15.900000 \\ 1118.590000 \\ 9.490000 \\ 131.480000 \\ 48.920000 \\ 5.850000 \\ 3.740000 \\ 1.050000 \\ 32.030000 \\ 5.690000 \\ 45.100000 \\ 12.430000 \\ 238.560000 \\ 28.750000 \\ 1.010000 \\ 119.290000 \\ 12.090000 \\ 31.180000 \\ 16.600000 \\ 29.670000 \\ 138.550000 \\ 17.420000 \\ 0.830000 \\ 
};
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2077.450000 \\ 762.100000 \\ 469.000000 \\ 143.600000 \\ 685.000000 \\ 3600.000000 \\ 20.200000 \\ 249.600000 \\ 269.000000 \\ 0.300000 \\ 0.200000 \\ 779.400000 \\ 1.800000 \\ 146.800000 \\ 1.300000 \\ 32.500000 \\ 137.000000 \\ 2016.400000 \\ 2.300000 \\ 33.900000 \\ 801.600000 \\ 2.200000 \\ 646.900000 \\ 3600.000000 \\ 1184.000000 \\ 627.000000 \\ 500.500000 \\ 238.300000 \\ 477.400000 \\ 3600.000000 \\ 17.800000 \\ 1726.800000 \\ 2.000000 \\ 316.700000 \\ 174.500000 \\ 2802.700000 \\ 335.300000 \\ 201.200000 \\ 1.100000 \\ 247.100000 \\ 2705.100000 \\ 156.900000 \\ 5.100000 \\ 2342.500000 \\ 3600.000000 \\ 3600.000000 \\ 72.700000 \\ 47.400000 \\ 301.200000 \\ 1.600000 \\ 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\includegraphics[scale=.7]{mio.eps}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to change fill color, outliers' style (although for some problem they are not shown), median style and so on.
The manual writes:

```
Note that you should customize styles like boxplot/every box if you merely wish to change fill colors.
```

Being quite beginner I don't understand how to do it. For example at page 406 you can see squared outliers but I cannot see nothing in the code about it.  Could someone give me some hint or suggest some (possibly quick) tutorial about this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can achieve the effect you desire by adding `boxplot/every box/.style={fill=gray}` to the options list for the `axis` environment. Replace `fill=gray` with the style you wish to apply to the boxes.

Comment: @PaulGessler Thank you! Where can I find the list of all such attributes? Otherwise I'll need to google/ask for everything! :-)

Comment: It's all in the manual, you were in the right neighborhood but it wasn't used in any code directly near the quotation you listed. Once you know the name of a key (such as `boxplot/every box/`) you can click on it or search for it to find where it's directly described in the manual. There you will find examples of its usage. `:-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding my comment into an answer:

The OP's quoted passage from the manual tells us that the *key* `boxplot/every box` is used to change fill colors. The important thing is to recognize that this is a style and must be modified as such. I used `boxplot/every box/.style={fill=gray!50}` to modify the style for every box in the boxplot.

**Simplified MWE:**
*(Extra styling/data removed for brevity.)*

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
  boxplot/draw direction=y,
  boxplot/variable width,
  boxplot/every box/.style={fill=gray!50},
]
  \addplot[boxplot] table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    0.090000 \\ 
    0.440000 \\ 
    0.120000 \\ 
    0.060000 \\ 
    0.320000 \\ 
    0.230000 \\ 
    0.440000 \\ 
  };
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]